# Using bernoulli's inequality to prove limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

[image]

I was thinking squeeze theorem with bernoulli but i can't find anything that  is always  smaller than it that goes to 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead, consider $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln\left[p^{1/n}\right] = \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\ln p$. If this limit exists and equals $L$, then the original limit exists and equals $e^L$.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Generalization),

> **Bernoulli's inequality.** For $x>-1$ and $0\le r \le 1$, we have $$(1+x)^r \le 1+rx.$$

Let $p=1+x$. Since $p>0$, we have $x > -1$. This gives $$p^{1/n} =(1+x)^{1/n} \le 1+(x/n) \to 1$$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Do you have something to bound it below when 0<p<1

Comment: I believe my solution works for all $p>0$ as written. I may be using a different version of Bernoulli's inequality than you, however.

Comment: @angryavian: for $p\lt1$, your inequality only gives an upper bound. The only lower bound is $0$.

Comment: @Matt: try the argument above for $1+x=1/p\gt1$. Then Bernoulli gives an upper bound, and we have the lower bound of $1$.